# What (fractional) exponent rule is being used here?

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

Here is the example we were given:

***Given that $32√2 = 2^a$, find the value of $a$.***

Here's the working out that was supplied:

$$32√2 = 2^5 \times 2^\frac{1}{2} = 2^\frac{11}{2}$$
$$a = \frac{11}{2}$$

I'm confused about how this:

$$2^5\times2^\frac{1}{2}$$

Was converted into this:

$$2^\frac{11}{2}$$

What happened?

Thank you.

Comment: $m^p\times m^q=m^{p+q}$

Comment: And $5+\frac12 = \frac{10}2+\frac12 = \frac{11}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^+,\ y \in \mathbb{Q},\ z \in \mathbb{Q}$

$$ x^yx^z = x^{y+z}. $$

Therefore, $2^5\times2^{\small\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{5 +\small\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{\small\frac{10}{2} + {\small\frac{1}{2}}} = 2^{\small\frac{11}{2}}$